# Получение рандомного значения из выбранного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.x, консоль

Есть 3 списка `a, b, c`.
Смысле программы:

User выбирает список: a, b или c (жанр) и получает случайное значение из этого списка.

Не могу сообразить, как сделать запрос на список от пользователя, и дальнейший вывод случайного значения.

Если Вам не трудно, пожалуйста, оставляйте комментарии в коде, чтобы было более понятнее.

---

```
import random

a = [   #1-й список
"Название: Назад в будущее\nГод: 1985 г.\nРежисёр: Роберт Земекис"  ,
"Название: Марли и Я\nГод: 2008\nРежисёр: Дэвид Френкел"    ,
"Название: Горячие головы\nГод: 1991 г.\nРежисёр: Джим Абрахамс"    ,
]

b = [   #2-й список
"Название:Мы из будущего\nГод: 2008 г.\nРежисёр: Иван Иванов",
"Название: Т-34\nГод: 2018\nРежисёр: Фарел Уилсон"  ,
"Название: Штурм 3-го Рейха\nГод: 2011 г.\nРежисёр: Поль Леквинд"   ,
]

c = [   #3-й список
"Название:Большой куш\nГод: 20011 г.\nРежисёр: Хлои Ридер",
"Название: Кушать подано\nГод: 2007\nРежисёр: Майкл Джей Уилсон"    ,
"Название: Умереть за 34 секунды\nГод: 2013 г.\nРежисёр: Ти Джей Уокер" ,
]

#######################___НАЧАЛО__################################

secure_random = random.SystemRandom ()

rez = a,b,c () #Объединяем списки в одну переменную

rez = (input("Введите жанр: a | b | c? "))
   if rez = a:
      print (secure_random.choice (a))
   elif rez = b:
      print (secure_random.choice (b))
   else rez = c:
      print (secure_random.choice (c))
```

Comment: Оператор сравнения - ==, а не =

Comment: Строчку "rez = a,b,c ()" нужно убрать. Она а) не нужна; б) ничего не дает, учитывая следующую строку.

Comment: @Эникейщик         большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После всего выше сказанного, ваш пример может выглядеть так:

```
import random

a = [
"Название: Назад в будущее\nГод: 1985 г.\nРежисёр: Роберт Земекис"  ,
"Название: Марли и Я\nГод: 2008\nРежисёр: Дэвид Френкел"    ,
"Название: Горячие головы\nГод: 1991 г.\nРежисёр: Джим Абрахамс"    ,
]

b = [
"Название:Мы из будущего\nГод: 2008 г.\nРежисёр: Иван Иванов",
"Название: Т-34\nГод: 2018\nРежисёр: Фарел Уилсон"  ,
"Название: Штурм 3-го Рейха\nГод: 2011 г.\nРежисёр: Поль Леквинд"   ,
]

c = [
"Название:Большой куш\nГод: 20011 г.\nРежисёр: Хлои Ридер",
"Название: Кушать подано\nГод: 2007\nРежисёр: Майкл Джей Уилсон"    ,
"Название: Умереть за 34 секунды\nГод: 2013 г.\nРежисёр: Ти Джей Уокер" ,
]

while True:
    rez = (input("Введите жанр: a | b | c | (иначе выход): "))
    if rez == 'a':
        print (random.choice(a))
    elif rez == 'b':
        print (random.choice(b))
    elif rez == 'c':
        print (random.choice(c))
    else:
        break
    print()
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в период 1-й сессий из любого списка "a/b/c" - выпадает одно и тоже значение. Возможно ли "рандомить" в одной сессии по всем значениям списка?

Comment: У меня выпадают разные значения, выборы делаются с равной вероятностью.

Comment: Хорошо ..... СПАСИБО!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import random
   ...:
   ...: a = [   #1-й список
   ...: "Название: Назад в будущее\nГод: 1985 г.\nРежисёр: Роберт Земекис"  ,
   ...: "Название: Марли и Я\nГод: 2008\nРежисёр: Дэвид Френкел"    ,
   ...: "Название: Горячие головы\nГод: 1991 г.\nРежисёр: Джим Абрахамс"    ,
   ...: ]
   ...:
   ...: b = [   #2-й список
   ...: "Название:Мы из будущего\nГод: 2008 г.\nРежисёр: Иван Иванов",
   ...: "Название: Т-34\nГод: 2018\nРежисёр: Фарел Уилсон"  ,
   ...: "Название: Штурм 3-го Рейха\nГод: 2011 г.\nРежисёр: Поль Леквинд"   ,
   ...: ]
   ...:
   ...: c = [   #3-й список
   ...: "Название:Большой куш\nГод: 20011 г.\nРежисёр: Хлои Ридер",
   ...: "Название: Кушать подано\nГод: 2007\nРежисёр: Майкл Джей Уилсон"    ,
   ...: "Название: Умереть за 34 секунды\nГод: 2013 г.\nРежисёр: Ти Джей Уокер" ,
   ...: ]
   ...:

In [2]: data = dict(a=a, b=b, c=c)

In [3]: random.choice(data[input('Choice: ')])
Choice: a
Out[3]: 'Название: Марли и Я\nГод: 2008\nРежисёр: Дэвид Френкел'

In [4]: random.choice(data[input('Choice: ')])
Choice: b
Out[4]: 'Название: Штурм 3-го Рейха\nГод: 2011 г.\nРежисёр: Поль Леквинд'

In [5]: random.choice(data[input('Choice: ')])
Choice: c
Out[5]: 'Название: Кушать подано\nГод: 2007\nРежисёр: Майкл Джей Уилсон'
```

У вас ошибка в операторе сравнения, вы вместо него поставили оператор присваивания и `else` не принимает условие:

```
In [6]: inp = input('Choice:')

In [7]: if inp == 'a':
   ...:     print(random.choice(a))
   ...: elif inp == 'b':
   ...:     print(random.choice(b))
   ...: else:
   ...:     print(random.choice(c))
```

И какая необходимость использовать `random.SystemRandom`?
Он использует `os.urandom` и доступен не на всех системах.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!!!